# Javascript split() Regex expression returns unwanted comma in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

I wrote a simple Regex to determine if the text box is filled only with numbers.

```
document.getElementById("id").value.split(/\d/).length;
```

if result of this line equals 0 then statement is true, but it seems like `value.split(/\d/)` returns a comma when I `alert()` it so length is 1 (`alert()` returns only what was written when I use it for `value`)

This works flawless in ie, but in chrome I get a comma. Why would this happen, is my regex incorrect? I also tried `/^\d+$/` but got the same results.

Comment: Which version of IE do you use?

Comment: It's 10.0.92, the latest I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/tests) method is more appropriate:

```
/^\d+$/.test(document.getElementById('id').value)
```

For example:

```
> /^\d+$/.test('1234')
true
> /^\d+$/.test('12,34')
false
> /^\d+$/.test('abcd')
false
```

---

`.split(/\d/)` return array of *n+1* items. (n = the number of digits contained):

```
> '1234'.split(/\d/)
["", "", "", "", ""]
> '1234'.split(/\d/).length
5
> 'asdf'.split(/\d/)
["asdf"]
> 
'asdf'.split(/\d/).length
1
```

---

Why you get `,,,`? `alert` convert the argument to string:

```
> String('1234'.split(/\d/)) // === String(['', '', '', '', ''])
",,,,"
```

Comment: True that `test` is better but OP is probably trying to figure out why his/her code behaves differently in Chrome vs IE.

Comment: That has done it! Thanks @falsetru, now code works in both browsers. Still wonder why it returns the 5th item if input has 4 elements? I just checked it through Chrome Debugger and yes it returns array of n+1?

Comment: @SercanAltundaş, IE 10, 9, 8, 7 also return n+1 items array for me.  Think of `'A8B'.split(/\d/)`: it returns `['A', 'B']`. and `'8'.split(/\d/)` which return `['', '']`. (The first empty string is before the digit, the second empty string is after the digit).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a regex like this one:

```
var re = /^\d+$/;
```

Or simply negate `isNaN()` to get true or false on the number check:

```
// dunno if you have to parseInt() first, haven't tested it
if(!isNaN(document.getElementById("id").value)){
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is happening is because if you split an empty string, you still get an empty string.

```
"".split("abc") // returns [""]
```

So the array has one element. This is the proper behaviour.

The same behaviour happens when you split a different string using a string that is not entailed in your original string:

```
"dsfsf".split("123") // returns ["dsfsf"]
```

The reason why this is "working" on IE is because the implementation in that browser is actually wrong, because the function should always return n+1 elements (i.e. at least the original string).